# VBScript chr() appears to return wrong value

Tags: javascript, vbscript, fromcharcode, chr

I'm trying to convert a character code to a character with chr(), but VBScript isn't giving me the value I expect. According to VBScript, character code 199 is:

```
ï¿½
```

However, when using something like Javascript's String.fromCharCode, 199 is:

```
Ç
```

The second result is what I need to get out of VBScript's chr() function. Any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edited to reflect comments**

`Chr(199)` returns a 2-byte character, which is being interpreted as 2 separate characters.

- use `ChrW(199)` to return a `Unicode` string.
- use `ChrB(199)` to return it as a single-byte character

Comment: ChrB worked if I wasn't concatenating the character onto a string. ChrW appears to work with string concatenation (don't ask me why). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Encoding is the problem.  Javascript may be interpreting as latin-1; VBScript may be using a different encoding and getting confused.

Answer (score 0):

The `fromCharCode()` takes the specified `Unicode` values and returns a string.

The `Chr()` function converts the specified `ANSI` character code to a character.