# How to call String.fromCharCode() in vbscript?

Tags: vbscript

I would like to call the String.fromCharCode() in vbscript. How to do it? I don't want to use javascript code on my site.

Comment: Why is this question tagged 'javascript'?

Comment: Can you use  ChrW()?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315719/vbscript-chr-appears-to-return-wrong-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ChrW() to get a Unicode string.
ChrB() to get a single-byte character.